# PostgreSQL Streaming Replication - LOG: archive command failed with exit code 1

Tags: postgresql

When I bring up the replica Node I am get the following error in the log

```
2020-04-27 00:12:26.278 EDT [3084] LOG:  archive command failed with exit code 1
2020-04-27 00:12:26.278 EDT [3084] DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/main/00000001000000000000000C && cp pg_wal/00000001000000000000000C /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/replica/00000001000000000000000C
```

### The achive command is set to below:

```
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/main/%f && cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/replica/%f'
```

**The configuration:**

Primary Server `postgresql.conf`:

```
wal_level = replica
wal_log_hints = on
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/main/%f && cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/replica/%f'
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 64
```

Standby server `postgres.conf`:

```
wal_level = replica
wal_log_hints = on
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/replica/%f && cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/main/%f'
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 64
hot_standby = on
```

`recovery.conf`:

```
standby_mode = on
primary_conninfo = 'host=192.168.56.103 port=5432 user=postgres password=****'
restore_command ='cp var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/replica/%f %p'
recovery_target_timeline ='latest'
```

Comment: The stderr of the cp command should probably be captured in the log file (perhaps depending on how you have logging set up).  What reason does cp give for failing?

Comment: Your `test` and your `cp` are referencing different directories.  Did you edit one place but not the other?

Comment: archive command failed with exit code 1 DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: test ! -f /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/replica/000000010000000000000006 && cp pg_wal/000000010000000000000006 /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/main/000000010000000000000006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out be a very simple solution. I had recovery.conf in the wrong directory. Doh!

I had the file in /etc/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf

when it should have been in the data directory: /var/lib/postgresql/10/main

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. You have `archive_mode = always` on the standby.

   Then the standby server will try to archive WAL segments (redundantly).
2. The standby server is not really a standby server, but a standalone database. That means that you have made a mistake setting up the standby server.

   The way to determine is that is the case, run

   ```
   SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
   ```

   If that returns `FALSE`, the server is *not* a standby.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do have archive_mode = on

Comment: Then it is not a standby server. Try `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();`, it should return `FALSE`. You must have made a mistake creating the standby. See the PostgreSQL log for details.

Comment: Replica return "False"

Comment: This cannot be. Either it is a primary, or `archive_mode = always`, otherwise PostgreSQL won't try to archive WAL segments. Perhaps you are confused and the errors you show are *not* from the standby?

Comment: Oh, I am dumb. You said it returns `FALSE`. So that proves it is *not* a standby server, and you made a mistake setting up replication. See my updated answer. Consult the log on the "standby" to see what happened.

Comment: No worries..  I posted a snippet of both Primary Postgresql.conf and "Standby" server files and Recovery.conf file above.. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.. Any advise would be greatly appreciated. Once again, appreciated the replies

Comment: That snippet is too short. You have to look at the log from where you initially started the standby server. I expect that there is no `started streaming` in there, rather an `archive recovery complete` or similar.

Comment: Your assumption is correct... This is log from Standby Server

Comment: 2020-04-28 14:45:19.142 EDT [10399] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5433
2020-04-28 14:45:19.142 EDT [10399] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5433
2020-04-28 14:45:19.144 EDT [10399] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"
2020-04-28 14:45:19.157 EDT [10400] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-04-28 14:44:50 EDT
2020-04-28 14:45:19.162 EDT [10399] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-04-28 14:45:19.732 EDT [10409] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet

Comment: This is log from primary

Comment: 2020-04-28 14:48:13.552 EDT [10483] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-04-28 14:48:13.552 EDT [10483] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2020-04-28 14:48:13.553 EDT [10483] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-04-28 14:48:13.567 EDT [10484] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-04-28 14:48:06 EDT
2020-04-28 14:48:13.572 EDT [10483] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-04-28 14:48:14.141 EDT [10492] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet